# Note from the nursery

Tags: toddler, pre-schooler

My 2.5 years old daughter don't follow the instructions at the nursery sometimes does that considered lack of focus?
When the nanny ask them to stand in a line to go to lunch sometimes my daughter stay standing and the nanny has to go back for her.
Although she's very smart she can count to 10 since 18 months she can tell the colors, shapes,and she memories sentences from the stories I read to her and she's emotionally healthy she express her feelings and recognize others feelings. Is that thing about the lunch line considered as a lack of focus? Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more precise in what way your daughter doesn't follow the instructions? Also, how elaborate are the instructions? For example, does she get a single instruction like "put your toys away, come stand in line and follow me to lunch" and your daughter gets distracted halfway through and forgets to move with the line?

Comment: The nanny ask all the children to stand in line so they go to have lunch,my daughter wouldn't follow them sometimes. It happened twice.

Comment: Twice for a three-year-old, and no other signs of trouble?  That seems like a "background noise" level of misbehavior for that age.  I wonder why the teachers are bringing that up--are you able to talk to them and find out if there are other signs of trouble that they are not mentioned in the note?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, yes I talked to them and I asked them for other signs if there's any and they didn't mention anything else! I was surprised and I told them that we should follow up with each other and that we should speak next week and now I'm doing my research about this because I'm familiar with the children development and I read all the time to be a better parent my husband as well.My daughter count to 10 since 18 months she have a big vocabulary in Arabic and English she express her feelings very well she notices small details in the stories I read to her so I was upset

Comment: I want to speak to them next week after I finish my readings about this to be fair to my daughter and to understand why her teacher think that! My daughter know the shapes, colors, she's very good in music, she know animals with their voices, she know the solar system with an information about each planet.and much more I'm not kidding I was really upset and sad and I felt like they were unfair with her and I asked them not to discuss this in front of her, please I need your opinion all,my daughter is smart and normal I believe in her very much. Can you give me your feedback please.Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have a hard time believing that a reasonable and reasonably trained teacher would call out your daughter's behavior as a lack of focus.

No 2.5yo has good focus, and the teacher should know that, because it's called childhood development.  All 2.5yo's should be expected to not notice things, forget things, bounce from one activity to another, and at times zone out and not respond to an adult's request, because this is what 2.5yo's do.

None of those behaviors are a result of a 2.5yo child trying to cause a problem.  Your daughter is simply being 2.5yo.

When my daughter had issues at daycare, the only way I was able to fully understand the situation was to visit the daycare and observe my daughter and how her teachers were interacting with her.

My daughter's daycare had a window from the hall into the classroom so I could watch without being in the room.   If you have to be in the room, a good way to observe is to pretend you're doing something on your phone, so that your daughter doesn't see you watching her.

My daughter needed extra supervision, and when I observed at my daughter's daycare it was clear that the teachers didn't understand the level of supervision that she needed, and I ended up pulling her out of daycare.

My daughter's teachers weren't bad, but uninformed, and not able to provide proper care for my daughter.

I would suggest that in addition to talking to the teachers, you visit your daughter's daycare to fully understand the situation.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer,yes I think I'll do this.